# Validate form in magento Javascript with red border in input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am validating my form using the following code:

`var customForm = new VarienForm('load_mini_form');`

This is working fine

screen-shot : [image]

But i want to validate with red border like below image.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use customForm.validate() if true form is valid clear border else add border to the box

Comment: when your function returns false add this just before `return false `statement `document.getElementById("yourElement").focus();`